# libgdx - measuring memory usage on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

The only thing I could find to get memory usage was

```
Gdx.app.getJavaHeap();

Gdx.app.getNativeHeap();
```

And this is very steady (polled once per second) at 10M and 7M respectively. I have two questions:

1. Does this mean my app uses only 17M of RAM? Because that seems kind of low.
2. Does this mean I don't have any significant memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Being stable at 10M is a good indicator, but it doesn't mean that this is all your app requires, it might be that blocks that consume memory were not reached.
2. Same for memory leak. It might just indicate that the right conditions were not reached.

However, if the opposite was true: if you app is steadily allocating more an more memory without releasing it, I would take that as a pretty good indication of a memory leak.

Comment: OK, so if after a while some random problems appear in my game (that libgdx documentation says are usually caused by a lack of memory) and the Java heap and native heap are still 10M and 7M (on a phone with 2GB of RAM), can I discount lack of memory as the problem? Nothing new is being loaded - resources are loaded at level start and the game plays fine for 15-20 minutes before problems appear.

Comment: I'd say yes. If your app's memory is stable and the phone is running out of memory that something else is gobbling it up.